# JS-DOM-creation , appendChild can't be executed?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

Hello I'm new and trying DOM-creation, but I'm stuck with weird problem with appendChild while the 1st try and 2nd it works but the 3rd I totally have no idea.
this is the my HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tugas Anchor DOM!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I will transform HTML with DOM to this :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tugas Anchor DOM!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="content">
        <div class="content-post">
          <h1>Judul Post</h1> <!-- IM STUCK HERE -->
          <button class="share-post-btn">Share this Post</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content-post">
          <h1>Judul Post 2</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but Im stuck to create a new appendChild for `h1` which is another newChild by DOM too.
here's my js :

```
var menu = document.getElementById("main");
var mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
var newDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
var newDiv2 = document.createElement("div");
var newH1 =  document.createAttribute("h1");

var newButton =  document.createAttribute("button");

var createId = document.createAttribute("id");
var createAtt = document.createAttribute("class");

createId.value ="content";
createAtt.value = "content-post";

//top
mainDiv.setAttributeNode(createId);
menu.appendChild(mainDiv);

//1st
newDiv1.setAttribute('class','content-post');
mainDiv.appendChild(newDiv1);


var judul1 = newDiv1.appendChild(newH1); //appendChild can't be executed here ?
// judul1.innerHTML = "Judul Post";

//2nd
newDiv2.setAttribute('class','content-post');
mainDiv.appendChild(newDiv2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `document.createElement` instead of `document.createAttribute` for `h1, span, p`

You should do:

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById('main');
var contentDiv = document.createElement('div');
var contentPostDiv1 = document.createElement('div');
var contentPostDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
var judul1 =  document.createElement('h1');
var judul2 =  document.createElement('h1');
var button =  document.createElement('button');

contentDiv.setAttribute('id', 'content');
mainDiv.appendChild(contentDiv);

contentPostDiv1.setAttribute('class','content-post');
contentPostDiv2.setAttribute('class','content-post');

contentDiv.appendChild(contentPostDiv1);
contentDiv.appendChild(contentPostDiv2);

judul1.innerHTML = 'Judul Post'
button.setAttribute('class', 'share-post-btn');
button.innerHTML = 'Share this Post'

contentPostDiv1.appendChild(judul1);
contentPostDiv1.appendChild(button);

judul2.innerHTML = 'Judul Post 2';

contentPostDiv2.appendChild(judul2);
```

Comment: ok thx, I didnt noticed that , 40mins++ tryin to figure out  method-call problem LOL

Comment: @DellWatson I've edited my response with a working example